# read_csv specifying dtype of a particular column to read as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dtype

I am trying to read a CSV file with the read_csv method. The column `item_number` needs to be read as a list.

Example :  `'item_number' : ['123456']`

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep =',', dtype = {'item_number' = list})
```

`dtype = {'item_number' = list}` ->does not work, while when I write it as `dtype = {'item_number' = str}` , it does work. Tried using converters but want to do it with dtype.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean by?

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep =',', dtypes = {'item_number': list})
```

But I am not sure with your dataset if that would work or not, so I guess you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep =',', dtypes = {'item_number': pd.eval})
```

**Edit:**

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep =',')
df['item_number'] = df['item_number'].str[1:-1].map(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think list is a valid pandas `dtype`. You can read it in as a string and subsequently convert it to a list

```
file_str = '''1|[123456]
2|[345678]'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_str), sep='|', header=None)
df[2] = df[1].apply(lambda x: list(x[1:-1]))
print(df)
#   0         1                   2
#0  1  [123456]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
#1  2  [345678]  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I want to read it inline while reading the csv.